# How to find out the processor model on Mac and Macbooks?

Tags: mac, macbook

the "About This Mac" won't show, and the "More Info..." won't show...

this thread talks about system_profiler but it is not on this macbook with Snow Leopard:

http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=43422

can it be found out?

Comment: That forum topic is from 2005, there weren't even Macbooks (i.e. Mac laptops with Intel chips) back then. The current operating system was 10.4 Tiger.

Comment: Please comment on answers if they're not satisfactory.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`System Profiler.app` (or `System Information.app` in newer versions of OS X) is located in `/Applications/Utilities/`. You can get there by pressing `Cmd-Shift-U` in Finder.

If it's not there, someone with administrator access to your machine messed up your system. Reinstall Mac OS X (or try to use [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) to restore `System Profiler.app` from your Mac OS X DVD).

---

`system_profiler` is the command-line equivalent (or `System Profiler.app` might be the GUI application to this CLI program). You need to enter `system_profiler` at a command prompt in `Terminal.app`. If you're only interested in your CPU and model, enter

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType
```

Output looks something like this:

```
Hardware Overview:

  Model Name: MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro6,2
  Processor Name: Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed: 2,66 GHz
  Number Of Processors: 1
  Total Number Of Cores: 2
  L2 Cache (per core): 256 KB
  L3 Cache: 4 MB
  Memory: 4 GB
  Processor Interconnect Speed: 4.8 GT/s
  Boot ROM Version: MBP61.0057.B0C
  SMC Version (system): 1.58f16
  Serial Number (system): W80253LDAGZ
  Hardware UUID: 598781DD-929A-1337-F00D-EF19A1B625F8
  Sudden Motion Sensor:
      State: Enabled
```

---

An alternative to using the System Profiler is [Mactracker](http://www.mactracker.ca/), an application containing a database of all Mac models made so far. If you know your model (e.g. "Macbook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2010)" and your order number (e.g. "MC373LL/A") you can find out your processor (M 620 with 2.66GHz for the example).

Comment: You can get the full model number without installing Mactracker, using the method @AlexT answered below (and get even more data by augmenting it using rbanffy's script, also below).

Comment: Unfortunately the CPU information given by System Profiler isn't very useful. I'm looking at a "2.7 GHz Intel Core i5" and a "2 GHz Intel Core i5"; it's only when you know that the former is an i5-5257U and the latter is an i5-6360U that you know that the "2 GHz" CPU is actually faster than the "2.7 GHz" CPU.

Answer (score 218):

You can find the full model number with the following command ([source](http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/15/get-cpu-info-via-command-line-in-mac-os-x/)):

```
sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string
```

This will return something like:

> Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2760QM CPU @ 2.40GHz

Comment: This is the most accurate answer

Comment: This is the right answer System information just tells you the processor brand. i7 is friggin useless! There are 4 generations of processors intel labeled i7

Comment: Is there a database of this info for various Mac models? Seems like for some reason Apple doesn't list this info in their sales materials.

Answer (score 13):

Adding to @AlexT's answer,

```
open http://www.google.com/?q=$(sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string | awk '{FS=" " ; print $2 "+" $3 "+" $4}')+site:ark.intel.com
```

Comment: brilliant idea!

Comment: Added it to https://gist.github.com/rbanffy/9c806ba406dba9a5afa324d0be3b8f13 for a more permanent presence.

Comment: I added a bit more https://github.com/Haroenv/mac-processor-info

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find any way to check it with software, but on this site: http://www.everymac.com you can find more details than system profiler provides (including cpu model)